# JS arrays - advanced assignment

Tags: javascript

This is related to the arrays in Javascript, which I am trying to use in a complex logic.

Consider the following code:

```
a['a1'] = 'AJA'
```

We know that, this is same as `a.a1 = 'AJA'` (provided proper definitions were given).

So, if we go ahead and interpret this:

```
console.log(a.a1[0])
console.log(a.a1[1])
console.log(a.a1[2])
console.log(a.a1)
```

It logs :

```
A
J
A
AJA
```

**Now, all I need is to assign a new character at the 4th position.**

When I try `a[a1][3] = 'Y'` or `a.a1[3] = 'Y'` and then try `console.log(a.a1)`, It still displays `AJA` instead of `AJAY`.

I know that we can do this using string concatenation, i.e. 
`a['a1'] = a['a1'] + 'Y'` and get this accomplished.

But why wasn't the first method working? By what other ways can do this?

Comment: please don't use arrays with custom properties, btw, it is not an array problem, but a string problem.

Comment: If you want to achieve this behaviour you need to declare the string as an array of chars. `var str = "AJA"; --> var strArr = ["A","J","A"];`, when you finish editing the char-array you need to transform it back to the string.

Comment: `var str = "AJA"; var strArr = str.split(''); strArr[3] = "Y"; str = strArr.join('');`

Comment: @LearnHowToBeTransparent This could have worked for a simple array. But not here..

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable. It means that if you create a string, you can't modify it anymore. So your `a1` doesn't know anything about 4th character.

You can see this example. I try to change the second char of the already created string, but it will not be changed anymore.

```js
let a  = {};
a['a1'] = 'AJA';

a.a1[1] = 'A';

console.log(a.a1);
```

For more you can see **[MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access)**

Comment: Yes they are immutable. But does it mean that string concatenation is the only way to get this done?

Comment: @A.J. there are many ways to do it. But the string concatenation is the simple one

Comment: "By what other ways can do this?"

Comment: You can create a function to get parameters char and index, but under the hood you need to use string concatenation :)

Comment: You're basically confirming what the OP already figured out, without providing an answer.

Answer (score -2):

As I know a[a1][3] or a.a1[3] is a string variable, you can treat it as:

var s = 'ss';

When you evaluate s[0] you'll get a string value. So when you assign any string value to s, you'll not get 'ss' + anyvalue but anyvalue instead. :)

Comment: There’s no assignment to the string itself, only to a property (not `s = …` but `s[2] = …`). How does this relate to the question?

Comment: Just an example, when you try to evaluate a[a1][3] or a.a1[3] you'll get the same type as the example I referred above. try typeof(a[a1][3])